# Алгоритм последовательности 2an-2–2, где a1=3 и a2=2

Tags: java, алгоритм

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как составить алгоритм по заданию с чего нужно начать?

Создайте программу, выводящую на экран 12 первых элементов последовательности
 2a<sub>n+1</sub> = 2a<sub>n</sub>-2–2, где a<sub>1</sub>=3 и a<sub>2</sub>=2.

**UPD**
без использования массива

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Взять три переменные: A1, A2, A3.

1. A1 = 3
2. A2 = 2
3. A3 = f(A2, A1)
4. Вывести A3
5. A1 = A2, A2 = A3
6. Повторить с шага 3, пока не достигнут нужный элемент

Comment: Там галочка есть, чтобы принять понравившийся ответ

Comment: нет просто один раз нажал и не какого действия думал что после нажатия должна страница обновиться

Comment: После нажатия там галочка появляется. Кстати, сейчас там в итоге, ни один не принят... =)

Answer (score 3):

Начать нужно, очевидно, с цикла.

```
int a = 3;
for (int number = 1; number <= 12; number++) {
   a = (2*a-4);
   System.out.println(a);
}
```

Воть. Синтаксис javaВСКИЙ.
Прошу прощения, если выдаст ошибку: на яве не прогал вообще. =) Но, думаю, вам надо только принцип? ;)

**UPD**
выведет 12 элементов, но до тринадцатого (a2-a13) так как a1 уже задан.

```
for (int number = 1; number < 12; number++) {
```

Так - 12

Answer (score 2):

Высылаю класс, решающий данную задачу с помощью рекурсивной формулы:

```
public class Test {

    private static int f(int x) {
        if (x == 1) {
            return 3;
        } else if (x == 2) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 2 * f(x - 2) - 2;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " : " + f(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, что решение Вам подойдет.

С уважением, Евгений.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int a1=3, a2=2, a3=0;
    for (int i=1; i<=12; i++) {
        a3 = 2*a1-2;
        System.out.print(a3 + " ");
        a1=a2;
        a2=a3;
    }
```